# how to make flip animation in UICollectionViewCell with array of images swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to implement flip animation in UICollectionViewCell. I have done it with 2 types of images. But I don't know how to implement it in array of images. The logic now:
[image]

but I want logic like this:
[image]

this is my code:

```
 import UIKit

    class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var coImage: UIImageView!

    let cardBackTag = 0
    let cardFrontTag = 1

    var cardViews: (frontView: UIImageView, backView: UIImageView)?

    var imgViewFront: UIImageView!
    var imgViewBack: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        imgViewFront = self.createCardWithImage(imageName: "1", tag: self.cardFrontTag)
        imgViewBack = self.createCardWithImage(imageName: "2", tag: self.cardBackTag)
        cardViews = (frontView: imgViewFront, backView: imgViewBack)
        contentView.addSubview(imgViewBack)
    }
    private func createCardWithImage(imageName: String, tag: Int) -> UIImageView {
        let newCardImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.frame)
        newCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        newCardImageView.tag = tag

        return newCardImageView
    }

    func flipCardAnimation(indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if (imgViewBack.superview != nil) {
            cardViews = (frontView: imgViewFront, backView: imgViewBack)
        }else{
            cardViews = (frontView: imgViewBack, backView: imgViewFront)
        }

        let transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft

        UIView.transition(with: self.contentView, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, animations: {

            self.cardViews!.backView.removeFromSuperview()

            self.contentView.addSubview(self.cardViews!.frontView)

        }, completion: { finished in
            print(indexPath)
        })
    }
}
```

and

```
import UIKit


class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var reuseIdentifier = "CollectionViewCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 8
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.flipCardAnimation(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Please, help me to implement this logic! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: you need to pass `array` of images into `CollectionViewCell` and when your `didSelectItemAt ` get called switch back and forth image from your `array`.

Comment: smthng like this?? var array = [["img1", "img2"], ["img3", "img4"], ["img5", "img6"], ["img7", "img8"]]

Comment: yes like so and now according to indexPath switch back and forth. you can also achieve without making array of array as your current image always `currentImage = (indexPath.row * 2)  + 1`.

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: Hi! My skills in programing are not strong) I still trying..